# Perl SOAP::WSDL support SOAP 1.2?

Tags: perl, soap, wsdl

I am using [`SOAP::WSDL`](https://metacpan.org/module/SOAP%3a%3aWSDL) to parse a WSDL file to a web service client, but in the WSDL file the SOAP version is SOAP 1.2 and `SOAP::WSDL` crashes when meeting such a SOAP version.

When I change the SOAP version to SOAP 1.1 it works well.

So I have a question, how can I make my `SOAP::WSDL` support SOAP 1.2 when parsing a WSDL file?